# can't read extras from expo `app.config.js` if metro server is runned first

Tags: expo

I have some key values in `extra` (app.config.js) of expoJS.

example:

```
extra: {
   someKey: "someValue",
},
```

when I'm running  `expo run:ios` everything is working, but if I run `expo start --dev-client` and then  press `i` to run ios emulator I can't get `extra`'s. that's how I'm trying to get them: Constants.manifest?.extra?.API_URL (once again, everything is working fine if I'll do `expo run:ios` directly.)

expo version: `"expo": "~46.0.9"`
expo CLI version: `6.0.5`

What I'm missing?

P.S. I need this because my physical phone is not able to connect to metro and I'm building an app into the phone first and then starting the metro server.